# Provide an example of a function which is insensitive to changes in input when the output is close to zero

Tags: functions

## Table of Contents

I have divided the question details into two sections:

1. A formal section.
2. An informal section.

## INFORMAL

Suppose that a person is trying to rotate a digital copy of a text-document using a computer.

The person is given a slider bar, where the slider bar values range from $-1$ to $+1$

[image: PICTURE_OF_A_GUI_SLIDER_BAR]

We want function $f$ which maps slider-bar input from $[-1, +1]$ to degrees of rotation.

If the document is almost straight up and down, then the the end-user should have extremely fine-grained control over how much to rotate. When the slider-bar input is near zero, then huge amounts of sliding should only rotate the image by tiny amounts (e.g. $0.1$°).

However, when the image needs to be rotated a lot, we should have course adjustments, not fine-adjustments. Moving the slider bar only a millimeter will cause rotation to jump from $40°$ to $45°$

I am looking for a function which looks like the following `.JPEG`:

[image: PLOT_OF_EXAMPLE]

## FORMAL

I am looking for an example of a mathematical function $f$ having certain properties:

- The domain of $f$ should be the real-interval $[-1, 1] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$
- The range of $f$ should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$
- $f(0) = f(0)$
- If $x$ is negative, then $f(x)$ should be negative. If $x$ is positive, then $f(x)$ should be positive:

  > $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)/abs(f(x)) = x/abs(x)$, where $abs$ is the absolute-value.
- $f$ should be smooth, not jagged or bumpy:

  > $f$ should be differentiable across its entire domain
- The further from zero you are, the greater the rate of change should be:

  > $\forall r, R \in \mathbb{R}$, if $R \geq 0$ and $r \geq 0$ and $R > r$, then $df/dx(R) > df/dx(r)$.
- $\forall r, R \in \mathbb{R}$, if $R \geq 0$ and $r \geq 0$ and $R > r$, then $f(R) > f(r)$.
- $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $abs(f(x)) = f(abs(x))$
- $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $(-1)*f(x) = f((-1)*x)$

People often complain that my questions have no correct answer.
Although there is no ***unique*** answers, there certainly are correct ones.

We define any example of a function having the properties listed above to be a "***correct***" answer.

## CLOSING OBSERVATIONS

#### Note 1

I was thinking about $f(x) = (-1 + 100^{abs(x)})/100$.
However, then $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$

---

#### Note 2

$f(x) = x^{3}$ satisfies all of the formal criterion.
However, from an *informal* standpoint, I am not sure that $f(x) = x^{3}$ makes for the most comfortable slider-bar possible.

There is a field known as "**user-experience design**" (**UX Design**). See [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

However, more than $50%$ of **UX** design professionals cannot do any math beyond basic multiplication and addition. Those who design user-experiences are often artists concerned with color schemes, font-choices, and graphic design in-general.

I thought asking on the math stack-exchange might prove more fruitful.

---

#### Note 3

A sort of guiding principle for answering this question is to formalize sloppy intuition about ease-of-use in adjusting the rotation of scanned documents. My heuristics are not great, and I am open to suggestions.

If you are uncomfortable with the informal aspects of this question, then go find a different question on [stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and leave me alone.
"*Live and and let live*," so-to-speak....
Go work on stack overflow questions you like, instead of deleting mine.

I will paint by house pink with with purple polka-dots.
You can paint your house a mono-tone grey

However, insisting that I paint my house grey just like yours, is not nice.
Stop reporting and deleting my questions.

Comment: Well, at least you put effort into your question.

Comment: I think $y={\rm sgn}\,x \cdot 40x^4$ is aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Why isn't $ f(x) = x^3$ good enough? You want the function to be "flatter"? Then just do, $f(x) = \frac{1}{64}x^3$ or .$ \frac{1}{1000}x^3$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Adjusting a constant coefficient will not work. I want to adjust the output so that the maximum of the domain (1) corresponds to a maximum a in the range. The range-max represent number of degrees of rotation (probably 45 degrees). If we adjust the shape of the function by playing with a constant coefficient, it will violate the constraint $f(1) = 45$

Comment: Why do you want it to rotate only between -45 and +45? Don't you want -180 to +180, or -360 to +360?